# Permission denied for other users than root

Tags: file-permissions, user, read-only, fedora-17

I have a directory called `sai` at `/var/www/html/`. I gave permission initially `755` and tried `777`. I have loggen in as user `nitish`. When I tried to edit the files , it says the file is `read-only`. But if I edit files through `terminal` logging as `root`, I can edit the same files. Below is `ls -l` command output:

```
[root@localhost sai]# ls -l
total 48
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 5508 Mar 30 15:40 build-my-website.html
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  674 Mar 30 15:40 check.html
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Mar 30 15:40 css
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar 30 15:40 images
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9002 Mar 30 15:40 index.html
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar 30 15:40 js
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4589 Mar 30 15:40 overview.html
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Mar 30 15:40 slider
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File permissions aren't inherited from parent directory on change. This is what `ls`'s first column means: (`rwx` is read, write, execution)

```
[directory] [owner perms] [group perms] [everybody else's prems]
     d           rwx           r-x                r-x
```

As you can see, only owner (`root`, third column of `ls`) can write to the file. You can use `chmod` to allow everybody edit these files:

```
chmod go+w *
```

or:

```
chmod a+w *
```

First command means:

> Allow (+) group members (g) and others (o) write (w) to the file, for all files (*).

Second one is

> Allow everybody (a) write to the file.

Comment: Thank you very much..I have been looking for this answer . Thanks for the explanation